# RubyDNS otherwise not working

Tags: ruby

I am using RubyDNS.
When I use match block and otherwise, I want to skip some addresses in match so they would be caught by otherwise block.
But it doesn't go to otherwise block.

```
RubyDNS.run_server(listen: INTERFACES, asynchronous: false) do
  upstream = RubyDNS::Resolver.new([[:udp, "8.8.8.8", 53], [:tcp, "8.8.8.8", 53]])

  match(/^([\d\.]+)\.in-addr\.arpa$/, IN::PTR) do |transaction, match_data|

    domain = nil # just for test

    if domain
      transaction.respond!(Name.create(domain))
    else
      # Pass the request to the otherwise handler
      # !!! this doesn't work
      false
    end
  end

  otherwise do |transaction|
    transaction.passthrough!(upstream)
  end
end
```

When I return false from match block - it doesn't go to otherwise block.
How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I found how to continue to otherwise block from match block: use 'next!'

```
match(/^([\d\.]+)\.in-addr\.arpa$/, IN::PTR) do |transaction, match_data|

domain = nil # just for test

if domain
  transaction.respond!(Name.create(domain))
else
  # Pass the request to the otherwise handler
  next!
end
end
otherwise do |transaction|
   transaction.passthrough!(upstream)
end
```

Comment: The documentation is here: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubydns/RubyDNS%2FRuleBasedServer%3Anext%21